# Channel entry not showing up on homepage

Tags: templates, entry

For some reason my channel entry stopped working on homepage (index.html) template. I am calling the same channel entries in the header and footer and I am completely stumped as to why it stopped working. Any ideas what the issue is?

**UPDATE**: I just took another look at code in embed header, head and footer and anything in channel entry `{exp:structure:entries channel="pages"}` is not being called, however working on all other pages and templates.

**ANSWER**: The issue was caused because "Make Entry Sticky" was unchecked. By checking that, all of my entry data outputted correctly.

Here's a look at code:

```
{embed="embeds/head"}
{embed="embeds/header"}

        <!-- START Main Content -->
        <div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <div class="col-main">
                    <div class="visual-area">
                        {exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}
                            {homepage_main_images}
                            <article class="visual-box {if "{color}" == "Orange"}orange-box{/if} {if "{color}" == "Light Blue"}blue-box{/if}">
                                <a href="{site_url}store/index.php/door-machinery.html">
                                    <div class="product-img-box">
                                        <p class="product-image"><img src="{image}" height="561" width="307" alt="{alt}"></p>
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <p>{content}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <header class="head">
                                        <h1>{title}</h1>
                                    </header>
                                </a>
                            </article>
                            {/homepage_main_images}
                        {/exp:channel:entries}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {embed="embeds/sidebar_nav_left"}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Main Content -->

{embed="embeds/footer"}
```

Comment: Did you try adding dynamic="no" to the entries loop?

Comment: Jean, yes I did. Added all values for `dynamic` parameter with no luck.

Comment: Did you try moving the title outside your homepage_main_images tag pair to see if perhaps there might be a naming conflict occurring?

Comment: Showing a ton of entry titles from other structure entry pages. No idea what the heck is going on.

Comment: Found the issue...included in original discussion post with answer to resolve. Thanks for the help!